# How to override an instance method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, overriding

Okay, I have a question about how to do something in ruby. I have a python example to show what I'm going for, so here it goes.

```
 class TestScript:
       def say(word):
           pass
       def x():
           self.say("hello") #right now it will pass
```

So lets Say that module was called "tester.py" but now, in another module we can do this now:

```
 import tester
 class doScript(tester.TestScript):
       def say(word):
           return word #now its overrided so in this current module it will return it rather pass it
```

Now the previous say def that was passed is voided by the new one so now if something gets passed to say it will return it rather pass it. Is there any way to do this in ruby? thanks

Comment: Ruby's `require` is roughly similar to Python's `import`. And Ruby does allow one class to inherit from another. Also search the internet for "mixins" to see an alternative to inheritance in Ruby.

Comment: @FMc I edited my question if you want to give it another go, also I looked into mixins but I couldn't quite find anything on how to do it from another file,could you possibly show me? But I hope I edited the question to make more sense if it was too confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with three files: `animal.rb`, `dog.rb`, and `script.rb`.

```
# animal.rb
# Our base class.
class Animal
  def speak
    puts 'click-click'
  end
  def eat
    puts 'chomp-chomp'
  end
end

# dog.rb
# Dog inherits from Animal, but we override the speak() method.
require 'animal'

class Dog < Animal
  def speak
    puts 'woof-woof'
  end
end

# script.rb
# Demo script.
require 'dog'

d = Dog.new
d.speak
d.eat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always inherit from other class:

```
class BasicSay
  def say(text)
    puts prepare_text(text)
  end

  def prepare_text(text)
    do_something_with(text)
  end
end

class HtmlSay < BasicSay
  def say(text)
    "<p>" + prepare_text(text) + "</p>"
  end
end
```